# Access to output parameters when ObjectDataSource retrieves data from cache

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, output-parameter

I have an ObjectDataSource that it has an Output Parameter in its select method. And my ObjectDataSource is enabled caching.

When ObjectDataSource retrieves data from database, I have access to output parameter in `ObjectDataSource_Selected` Event.

But when data retrieves from cached version, `Selected` Event will not fire and I haven’t access to output parameter.

Is there any solution to access output parameters when ObjectDataSource retrieves data from cache?

Answer (score 0):

You could either store the output parameter value in Cache inside the ObjectDataSource_Selected event, or just refactor the stored procedure or query not to use an output parameter.

Comment: ObjectDataSource creates multiple cache versions for different inputs and if I want to cache output parameters for different cache versions, it will be a bit complex.